# How many files are required to load 3D object in ARKit?

Tags: ios, arkit

I am load 3D model in my app (3D models are copied from downloaded sample apps) , but sample app is working and when i am trying to change model file the model is not display.

In Apple sample AR app and many other sample code we seen that there is .scn or .dae files for load any 3D model.

My question is which files are required to load Object apart from .scn or .dae files ? Am i missed some file to include in my demo app ?

Comment: You only need .dae files for swift, you can use .obj file but preference is always for .dae files.

Comment: Thanks, my issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not even possible to consider answering it without knowing the 3rd party, so-called _sample_, project (from unknown source) and the own, so-called _demo_, project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solutuion for load 3D objects files.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
private var modelNode: SCNNode!


@objc func addObjectToSceneView(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)

    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

    guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first else { return }
    let translation = hitTestResult.worldTransform.translation
    let x = translation.x
    let y = translation.y
    let z = translation.z

    // For load .scn file 
    let tempScene = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/cat/cat.scn”)
    modelNode = tempScene.rootNode
    modelNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode)

    //For load .dae file
    let tempScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Petroleum_Lamp/Petroleum_Lamp.dae")
    modelNode = tempScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Lamp", recursively: true)!
    modelNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode)   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert .dae/.obj to .scn from here..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqw5a.png)